# Why 'Serialization of 'SplFileInfo' is not allowed?

Tags: php

I'm trying to store an array of `SplFileInfo` instances in a cache with `serialize` command but the command throws this exception:

```
Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SplFileInfo' is not allowed
```

Why is it not allowed?

Thanks!

**Note:** I'm just curious. The problem itself can be worked around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Objects based on `Resources` can't be serialized.

I guess I don't have to explain why (if you need the explanation tell me even if it's OT in this question)

### Addendum

For @Charles that doesn't believe that SplFileInfo doens't store/open a new resource I have made a little test script.

If you run this:

```
new SplFileInfo('index.php');
$link=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
echo $link;
```

The output is: Resource id #2

If you run this:

```
//new SplFileInfo('index.php');
$link=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
echo $link;
```

The output is: Resource id #1.

Comment: -1, factually incorrect.  `SplFileInfo` *is not* based on a resource type (you might be thinking of [`SplFileObject`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) instead), and failing to explain why resources can't be serialized doesn't help.

Comment: @yes, the fact that resources can't be serialized is very non-obvious to people that haven't worked with PHP.

Comment: @yes, I have been unable to duplicate your results showing that there's a resource handle being created by `SplFileInfo`. **Can you please post a more comprehensive, *verifiable* test case?**

Comment: @Charles: Actually running it again it's giving me not always the same results. Sometimes it returns `Resource id #1`, somtimes it returns `Resource id #2` So at this point I can't really say if splfileinfo always open a new handler or only under some circumstances

Answer (score 5):

`SplFileInfo` can not be serialized because the PHP team has marked it as unserializable.  Really, this isn't surprising: *The only actual data that a `SplFileInfo` object would contain would be the filename*.  Each method in the class is effectively a wrapper for the non-OO standard function that does the same thing.  These method calls are resolved *at call time*, not when the object is created, so serializing the object would *not* capture the state of the file as it was at serialize time.

If you're trying to build a list of files to remember later, build the list from the file names.

If you're trying to build a list of files and their properties at a specific time, then grab those properties and store *those* instead of the object.
*
Please keep in mind that PHP [caches the results of `stat`-based functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) for you, so there's no overwhelming need to add another caching layer.

---

[Here is the C file containing the underlying mechanisms for `SplFileInfo` and `SplFileObject`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/spl/spl_directory.c?view=markup).  The method SPL uses to open a file handle is called `spl_filesystem_file_open`.  If you search the file, you will see four references to it.  One is the function definition.  One is in the constructor for `SplFileObject`.  One is in the constructor for `SplTempFileObject`.

There are other references in there, when working with entities on the filesystem, of a definition called `SPL_FS_FILE`.  A switch statement with `SPL_FS_FILE` as one of the conditions is the fourth and final `spl_filesystem_file_open` call.  It's inside a function called `spl_filesystem_object_create_type`, which creates the *actual* internal structure that the various filesystem-based SPL objects work upon.  Note that right above the `SPL_FS_FILE` case is a `SPL_FS_INFO` case, which handles `SplFileInfo` cases, and note how that code does *not* contain a filehandle open.

**This is concrete proof that `SplFileInfo` *does not* contain a file handle resource.**

The file also contains the code that prevents `SplFileInfo` from being serialized, by marking it as not serializable... without comment.  Darn.

---

Debunking the resource issue even further at the PHP interactive prompt

```
[charles@duo ~/splfileinfo_test]$ touch a b c d e
[charles@duo ~/splfileinfo_test]$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $fh_a = fopen('./a', 'r');
php > echo $fh_a; # should be 1
Resource id #2
php > # WHAT.
php > $fh_b = fopen('./b', 'r');
php > echo $fh_b; # should be ... uh ... 3 now?
Resource id #3
php > $fi_c = new SplFileInfo('./c');
php > $fh_d = fopen('./d', 'r');
php > echo $fh_d; # should be 4 if SplFileInfo has no internal resource
Resource id #4
php > exit
[charles@duo ~/splfileinfo_test]$ php -v
PHP 5.3.6 (cli) (built: Mar 19 2011 07:44:03)
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: Actually you are wrong. SplFileInfo open a resource to a file and store it internally therefore it cannot be serialized.

Comment: Cite your source.  Perhaps you are thinking of [the `openFile` method](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.openfile.php), which returns a [`SplFileObject`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php), which *would* open the file.  `SplFileInfo` -- emphasis on the **`Info`** there -- is just a wrapper to file information functions, **none of which require that the file be opened.**

Comment: @charles: Editing my answer. Hang on.

Comment: @yes, I have updated my answer with concrete evidence that `SplFileInfo` does not contain a file handle.

Comment: I wouldn't call `concrete evidence` also give me some time to study that .c. Also we went completly OT than the OP question

Comment: @yes, indeed we have.  I have also now updated my post with an example showing, using real code, that SplFileInfo **does** not increment the resource counter.  I'm confused at how your example and mine differ.  Can you please try the example code?